# Merge several presentations

Tags: powerpoint, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I'm about to start write a large presentation. It will cover many different but related areas and I wish to keep this maintainable and simple.

I've worked with LaTeX before and in LaTeX it's possible to include other LaTeX-documents in the final render.

Is there any way to do this with Powerpoint, Libreoffice of other similar program?

Preferably I would keep the template and formatting in the master document and let the others just contain simple text, bullet-points and images.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what you need is exactly what LaTeX claim to offer : WYSIWYM (What you see is what you mean).

All WYSIWYG (What you see is what you get) programs such as Microsoft Powerpoint, Microsoft Word, LibreOffice Writer, LibreOffice Presentation and so on are designed to make the user feel like he write down his presentation on paper, or directly on a screen if this is the purpose of your work.

So I don't think that you can mix these two approaches, but :

1. Why not LaTeX : you know it, why wont you use it if you need it ?
2. Why not Libreoffice in a single document, this is designed to deal with huge content, you'll find every feature you need to navigate quickly from one part to the other BUT you'll have to use it the right way : Paragraph style, Page Style, Text Styles and so on

Comment: I'm not the sole maintainer of this new document but I'm the only one that knows LaTeX. And it would be great if we could work on the same document at the same time and off-line. I don't think that's possible even with a full Office suite.

Comment: You have the possibility to use cooperative functionnalities of LibreOffice, like traking changes, insert comments, use of templates... (from http://poland.gadgetstudy.com/Five-tips-cooperation-in-LibreOffice/)

But, if you and you team workers don't know these features, they'll have to learn to use something anyway, so why not teach them LaTeX (for the content, the "mean" part, it'll be easy I think) and you'll do the template and compilation stuff, instead of all learn to use LibreOffice TeamWork Features?

Answer (score 0):

If each section is independent and simply needs to be combined at "show time" (think: conference with a series of speakers) you could create an agenda/menu presentation with links to each of the subsidiary presentations.

If you actually need to combine all of the subsidiary presentations into one (eg for printing) you can use PPT's Reuse slides feature (it hides in different places for different versions; tell me which version you're using and I can give more detail) to bring the subsidiary slide presentations into one main one.  Or you can simply put both presentations into slide sorter view then copy/paste the slides into the main presentation; when it asks, tell PPT not to preserve the format of the incoming slides.

This could also be done in code but it doesn't seem that that's what you're looking for.